# Android Java - Setting text in a text box (either TextView or EditView) to not be editable by a user only by buttons

Tags: java, android, xml

I am attempting to create an app where I have 3 buttons and 4 text boxes
They idea follows this concept.

- Button1 (has a +1 symbol on it) Should provide a result in text box 1 of a random selection of arrayList1 which has 20 items this button should also update the current value of text box 4.
- Button2 (has a -1 symbol on it) Should provide a result in text box 2 of a random selection of arrayList2 which has 20 items this button should also update the current value of text box 4.
- Button3 (has a -6 symbol on it) Should provide a result in text box 3 of a random selection of arrayList3 which has 20 items this button should also update the current value of text box 4.

I also need to have a default value for text box 4 that starts with the numerical value of 4.

**Now to my actual question**
How do I set any of these buttons to do this while simultaneously making the text boxes not be editable by the user they should only populate from the button presses.

```
        // Create the ArrayLists
    ArrayList<String> plusOneList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> minusOneList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> minusSixList = new ArrayList<String>();

    //Adding items to list
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        plusOneList.add("1." + i+1 + "Until end of turn, up to one target creature gets +1/+1 and gains first strike, vigilence, and lifelink.");
        plusOneList.add("2." + i+1 + "Distribute three +1/+1 counters among one, two, or three target creatures you control.");
        plusOneList.add("3." + i+1 + "Destroy target noncreature permanent.");
        plusOneList.add("4." + i+1 + "Create two 3/1 red Elemental creature tokens with haste. Exile them at the beginning of the next end step.");
        plusOneList.add("5." + i+1 + "Create three 1/1 white Soldier creature tokens.");
        plusOneList.add("6." + i+1 + "Create a 3/3 black Beast creature token with deathtouch.");
        plusOneList.add("7." + i+1 + "Reveal the top five cards of your library. Put all creature cards revealed this way into your hand and the rest on the bottom of your library in any order.");
        plusOneList.add("8." + i+1 + "During target opponent's next turn, creatures that player controls attack Urza if able.");
        plusOneList.add("9." + i+1 + "Put a loyalty counter on Urza for each creature target opponent controls.");
        plusOneList.add("10." + i+1 + "Until your next turn, whenever a creature an opponent controls attacks, it gets -1/-0 until end of turn.");
        plusOneList.add("11." + i+1 + "Target player exiles a card from their hand.");
        plusOneList.add("12." + i+1 + "Reveal the top card of your library. If it's a land card, put it onto the battlefield. Otherwise, put it into your hand.");
        plusOneList.add("13." + i+1 + "Target land you control becomes a 4/4 Elemental creature with trample. It's still a land.");
        plusOneList.add("14." + i+1 + "Draw a card, then add one mana of any color to your mana pool.");
        plusOneList.add("15." + i+1 + "Until end of turn, Urza becomes a legendary 4/4 red Dragon creature with flying, indestructible, and haste. (He doesn't lose loyalty while he's not a planeswalker.)");
        plusOneList.add("16." + i+1 + "Until your next turn, creatures you control get +1/+0 and gain lifelink.");
        plusOneList.add("17." + i+1 + "Look at the top five cards of your library. You may reveal an artifact card from among them and put it into your hand. Put the rest on the bottom of your library in any order.");
        plusOneList.add("18." + i+1 + "Urza deals 3 damage to target creature or player.");
        plusOneList.add("19." + i+1 + "Until your next turn, whenever a creature deals combat damage to Urza, destroy that creature.");
        plusOneList.add("20." + i+1 + "Add X mana in any combination of colors to your mana pool, where X is the number of creatures you control.");
        minusOneList.add("1." + i+1 + "Urza deals 3 damage to each creature.");
        minusOneList.add("2." + i+1 + "Gain control of target creature.");
        minusOneList.add("3." + i+1 + "Urza deals 4 damage to any target and you gain 4 life.");
        minusOneList.add("4." + i+1 + "Destroy target creature. You gain life equal to its toughness.");
        minusOneList.add("5." + i+1 + "You get an emblem with \"Creatures you control get +1/+1.\"");
        minusOneList.add("6." + i+1 + "You may put a creature card from your hand onto the battlefield.");
        minusOneList.add("7." + i+1 + "Draw three cards, then put a card from your hand on top of your library.");
        minusOneList.add("8." + i+1 + "Target player puts the top ten cards of his or her library into his or her graveyard.");
        minusOneList.add("9." + i+1 + "Reveal the top five cards of your library. An opponent separates those cards into two piles. Put one pile into your hand and the other on the bottom of your library in any order.");
        minusOneList.add("10." + i+1 + "Exile target permanent.");
        minusOneList.add("11." + i+1 + "Reveal the top five cards of your library. You may put all creature cards and/or land cards from among them into your hand. Put the rest into your graveyard.");
        minusOneList.add("12." + i+1 + "Search your library for a card and put that card into your hand. Then shuffle your library.");
        minusOneList.add("13." + i+1 + "Target player sacrifices two creatures.");
        minusOneList.add("14." + i+1 + "Create a 5/5 black Demon creature token with flying. You lose 2 life.");
        minusOneList.add("15." + i+1 + "Create a 4/4 gold Dragon creature token with flying.");
        minusOneList.add("16." + i+1 + "Target player's life total becomes 10.");
        minusOneList.add("17." + i+1 + "Destroy target nonland permanent.");
        minusOneList.add("18." + i+1 + "Return target permanent from a graveyard to the battlefield under your control.");
        minusOneList.add("19." + i+1 + "Create two 3/3 green Beast creature tokens.");
        minusOneList.add("20." + i+1 + "Draw four cards and discard two cards.");
        minusSixList.add("1." + i+1 + "Urza deals 7 damage to target player or planeswalker. That player or that planeswalker's controller discards seven cards, then sacrifices seven permanents.");
        minusSixList.add("2." + i+1 + "You get an emblem with \"If a source would deal damage to you or a planeswalker you control, prevent all but 1 of that damage.\"");
        minusSixList.add("3." + i+1 + "Destroy all lands target player controls.");
        minusSixList.add("4." + i+1 + "Create X 2/2");
        minusSixList.add("5." + i+1 + "You gain 100 life.");
        minusSixList.add("6." + i+1 + "Urza deals 10 damage to target player and each creature he or she controls.");
        minusSixList.add("7." + i+1 + "You get an emblem with \"Creatures you control have double strike, trample, hexproof, and haste.\"");
        minusSixList.add("8." + i+1 + "You get an emblem with \"Artifacts, creatures, enchantments, and lands you control have indestructible.\"");
        minusSixList.add("9." + i+1 + "Create a 6/6 green Wurm creature token for each land you control.");
        minusSixList.add("10." + i+1 + "Each player shuffles his or her hand and graveyard into his or her library. You draw seven cards.");
        minusSixList.add("11." + i+1 + "Destroy up to three target creatures and/or other planeswalkers. Return each card put into a graveyard this way to the battlefield under your control.");
        minusSixList.add("12." + i+1 + "You get an emblem with \"Whenever you cast a spell, exile target permanent.\"");
        minusSixList.add("13." + i+1 + "You get an emblem with \"Whenever a creature enters the battlefield under your control, you may have it fight target creature.\" Then create three 8/8 blue Octopus creature tokens.");
        minusSixList.add("14." + i+1 + "You control target player during that player's next turn.");
        minusSixList.add("15." + i+1 + "Exile all cards from target player's library, then that player shuffles his or her hand into his or her library.");
        minusSixList.add("16." + i+1 + "Create three 1/1 black Assassin creature tokens with \"Whenever this creature deals combat damage to a player, that player loses the game.\"");
        minusSixList.add("17." + i+1 + "Put all creature cards from all graveyards onto the battlefield under your control.");
        minusSixList.add("18." + i+1 + "You gain X life and draw X cards, where X is the number of lands you control.");
        minusSixList.add("19." + i+1 + "Flip five coins. Take an extra turn after this one for each coin that comes up heads.");
        minusSixList.add("20." + i+1 + "You gain 7 life, draw seven cards, then put up to seven permanent cards from your hand onto the battlefield.");
```

**NOTE:**
All quoted text is curtesy of Wizards of the Coast and their product Magic The Gathering. Per their Terms of use it is free to use with the idea that they may take and use my code without guarantee of compensation. (I am personally fine with this)

Comment: Just a note I am currently taking an Intro to Mobile Programming class and I am stuck on this topic because it is not specifically covered in the class. I also am trying to add this as part of my final project for the class.

Comment: All quoted text is curtesy of Wizards of the Coast and their product Magic The Gathering. Per their Terms of use it is free to use with the idea that they may take and use my code without guarantee of compensation. (I am personally fine with this)

Comment: Thank you both for the heads up I am also new to StackOverflow and still trying to figure out its idiosyncrasies.

Comment: Why all this explaining and irrelevant code? Just set Enabled of the view to false is you only want the text of an EditText to be changeable by code. And a TextView can never be changed/edited by a user.

Comment: @blackapps The reason to show all that code and the explanations is because I am still learning and don't 100% understand what I am doing yet. I thought showing the magnitude of the data I was trying to call at random with an explanation of how I am trying to get it to work would assist in the aid I was asking for. If that is excessive and not needed I will attempt to curb that in the future.

Comment: You have too much irrelevant code, and you left out any button code. I'm not sure how we can help you if you don't post the actual code you're having problems with.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value to a `TextView` programmatically using `setText()` method.

Get a reference to your text views.

```
TextView textView1 = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
TextView textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
TextView textView3 = findViewById(R.id.textView3);
TextView textView4 = findViewById(R.id.textView4);
```

Get a reference to your Buttons

```
Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1)
Button button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2)
Button button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3)
```

Create a method to generate random number and set the text to respective Text view.

```
 private void updateData(TextView main, TextView other, List<String> list) {
        Random random = new Random();

        // generates a random number between 0 and size of list - 1
        int randomNumber = random.nextInt(list.size()); 

        // get the text stored at that position
        String text = list.get(randomNumber); 

        // update the main text view
        main.setText(text);  

        // update the other text view (the fourth text view)
        other.setText(text); 
    }
```

Add click listeners to all your button and call the above method with required parameters.

```
// Do this for other two button and change parameters as required.
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            updateData(textView1, textView4, plusOneList);
        }
    });
```